# Proof that Finite Turing Machine is reducible to Regular Turing Machine

Tags: computer-science, computability, turing-machines

I know that Finite Turing Machine and Regular Turing Machine are undecidable through Rice's theorem, but I may find a reduction among them?

Finite TM = {< M > | L(M) is finite on {a}}

Regular TM = {< M > | L(M) is regular on {a,b}}

Comment: What do you mean? Are you asking if there's a reduction from Finite TM to Regular TM and vice versa?

Comment: yes, just that!